# Is there a way to avoid hashing/equalityChecking when inserting to std::unordered_multimap?

Tags: c++, std

I'm Using `std::unordered_multimap mymap` as my data structure for holding and fast access to more than 10M elements (~10GBs data) of type `T` as key with custom and inevitably expensive hashing and equal (`operator==`) functions.

The problem is it takes way longer than what I am comfortable with (about 45 minutes or so) to load and store all of the dataset into mymap and since it won't change after the data is stored I decided to iterate over buckets and write their elements into separate files (serializing) so next time I would just create enough buckets, reserve memory, and directly put them in their places (deserializing) and avoid hashing and equality checking.

This would reduce loading times greatly. (down to ~60 secounds)

Sadly, I couldn't find a way to insert elements directly to the underlying data structures of `std::unordered_multimap` and bypass hashing/equalityChecking.

**UPDATE:**

- Turns out there was an error in my hashing algorithm which caused my elements to pile up in few buckets only, I fixed that and then it took only 81 seconds to load dataset into map. (down from ~45 minutes)
- As suggested by @aconcagua, I tried using precomputed hashes for my datatype and I reduced loading times down to 79 seconds. So it seems my hashing algorithm is not that expensive after all and I have tried my best to make sure my equality function is optimized down to each operation, it's not getting any faster I guess. I should investigate writing my own hash-map.

Comment: What do you look for seems like a "back door". It's hard to believe that the `std::unordered_multimap` offers such back-door although I understand why you need it. (I had a look on cppreference out of curiosity but couldn't find anything promising.) In such situations, I tend towards "build my own". (Too bad, if other code depends on concrete types which cannot be matched this way while in meta-programming, making the same "interface" should work without problems.) "Build my own" might be a questionable decision but we speak about rare cases where performance became a main issue, aren't we?

Comment: I wish I could upvote @Scheff's comment multiple times. It seems there is no real way to just 'memset' the map contents, but I would at least try and benchmark using `std::unordered_multimap::emplace_hint`. It for sure won't be as efficient as your goal, but might be efficient enough

Comment: @Fureeish `std::unordered_multimap::emplace_hint` catched my eye too. But: 1st I'm not sure how precisely `iterator`s are related to buckets. 2nd (probably even more important) I read hard concerns that the hint might be ignored at all. As far as I understood it, it's not mandatory for implementers to consider the hint.

Comment: @Scheff I don't know how good is the optimizer see things to create nodes in bulk, which affects performance the most, I guess. Anyway in c++17, there is `::node_type` so we can now splicing between maps very efficently. Unfortunately, manual `ctor` of `node_type` is curretnly [`undefined`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle) by `std`. Anyway I guess one might hackishly add his or her own `ctor` to create nodes outside the map at once effectively and insert (now also supports node_type!!) right after.

Comment: @sandthorn Loading large contents as bulk is something I can warmly recommend. (Using this trick, I once earned more boost than expected.) This, could be achieved when contents is stored in a `std::vector` while `std::unordered_multimap` just hashes the indices into this `vector`. However, this still leaves the task of hashing the contents again after loading (which may or may not be an issue). Your hint with [Node handle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle) is interesting - I will keep an eye on it.

Comment: @Kamran This "bitter juice" I once had also. Having replaced a `std::set` by `std::unordered_set` to remove duplicates from and re-index a giant vertex set, I realized that the `std::set` was not the bottleneck at all. Instead, there were just too much updates signalled to GUI. (And, it looked that promising in the synthetic test...) However, fixing the GUI issue, the performance of the whole became much better (e.g. 7 minutes instead of 38 hours). So, I once again learned how important it is to identify the _real_ bottleneck. ;-)

Comment: @Kamran Concerning your "accident" with the hash function: This is why I mis-trusted hashing for many years as I were in doubt if I would be able to find a suitable hash function for the specific data set which provides a sufficient distribution. In the above story, I learned about e.g. [Spooky Hash](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/spooky.html) which appeared to me like a universal hashing with good distribution for arbitrary data (which may occur in daily work). This took away my fears a bit but still I had rare (no) situations where I _needed_ a `std::unordered_set` (instead of `std::set`).

Comment: Sorry, if you guys have already played with this, when security is not concerned as much, Yann Collet's [xxHash](https://cyan4973.github.io/xxHash/) is quite popular hashing algorithm for speed today. There is also more [simple](https://create.stephan-brumme.com/xxhash/) implementation of Stephan Brumme that is way easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

`std::unordered_map` does not provide such functionality, you would rely on dirty hacks. So you could either write your own hash map allowing such operation - or you might recude time spent for hash calculation as follows:

```
class C
{
    size_t m_hashCode;
    bool m_isHashDirty;

public:
    C() : m_isHashDirty(true);

    size_t hashCode()
    {
        if(m_isHashDirty)
        {
             m_hashCode = /* result of complex calculations */;
        }
        return m_hashCode;
    }
};
```

Any modification of the object would set the dirty flag, but you'd calculate hashes only on need and if there was a change to previous call.

You'd of course store the hash code when serialising and restore it when deserialising, setting the dirty flag to false.

Equality operator offers less options to optimise, of course you can shortcut the result on first detected differing member, but equality won't be sure until last member checked. So you possibly might rather improve your hash function to produce less collisions.